# Update the Marker position on Maps on a new position change - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I have initialized a react native map with an initial region co-ordinate.

```
 <MapView
     style={{ ...styles.map, marginTop: this.state.marginTop }}
     initialRegion={this.state.region}
     showsUserLocation={true}
     followsUserLocation={true}
     onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
     onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}         
     >
     <MapView.Marker
     coordinate={this.state.region}
     title={"Your location"}
     draggable                  
     />
 </MapView>
```

Now fetching a new location from the server, which has a new latitude and longitude, which I want to display as a new marker on my maps. I have updated the region with new latitude and longitude on ononRegionChange.

But I'm unable to invoke the new marker position on the region change. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are updating the new region ?

Comment: this.setState({
                region: {
                  latitude: myArray[0],
                  longitude: myArray[1]
                },
this is how I'm updating the state

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something using which you can move the marker to new position then give the below suggestion a try.

We are using the same approach in our project, so I hope this would help!

```js
// When updating region
const coordinate = new MapView.AnimatedRegion({
  latitude: newRegion.latitude,
  longitude: newRegion.longitude,
  latitudeDelta: 0,
  longitudeDelta: 0,
});

this.setState({ region: newRegion, coordinate }, () => {
  if (!!this._markerRef) {
    coordinate.timing({
      latitude,
      longitude,
      duration: MARKER_ANIMATION_DURATION,
    }).start();
  }
})

// rendering MapView
<MapView
  style={[styles.map, { marginTop: this.state.marginTop }]}
  initialRegion={this.state.region}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  followsUserLocation={true}
  onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
  onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
>
  <MapView.Marker.Animated
    ref={ref => {this._markerRef = ref;}}
    coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
    title="Your location"
    draggable
  />
</MapView>;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `region` prop for `MapView` and update it when your `lat` and `long` changed. your state object should be an object like this as well:

```
this.state = { 
   mapRegion: {
     latitude: 14.343,
     longitude: 1600,
     latitudeDelta: 0.002,
     longitudeDelta: 0.0002,
   },
   markerCoordinate: {
     latitude: 14.343,
     longitude: 1600,
    }
}
```

and here is the `MapView`

```
 <MapView
     style={{ ...styles.map, marginTop: this.state.marginTop }}
     initialRegion={this.state.mapRegion}
     region={this.state.mapRegion}
     showsUserLocation
     followsUserLocation
     onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
     onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}         
   >
     <MapView.Marker
       coordinate={this.state.markerCoordinate}
       title={"Your location"}
       draggable                  
     />
 </MapView>
```

Note that you have to set both `mapRegion` and `markerCoordinate` on every data fetching from the server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but If I need to add multiple markers, how do I use the same code?

Comment: Hi. you just have to change the `markerCoordinate` state to an array and generate `MapView.Marker` with that array and pass each coordinate to each marker. ( use `map` loop to generate markers )